# finding a value in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object:

```
{
   id: 16, 
   defs: {
      name: "Depot (Float)", field: "Depot"
   }
}
```

And an array (which can have more than one object in it but for the purposes of this only has one):

```
[
  {
    Percentage Monthly Potential: 1, 
    Area Manager: "Ashar", 
    Business Unit: "Retail", 
    Cust no: 68345, 
    Depot Name: "Leicester", 
    Group Number: "", 
    Depot: 14, 
    Target: 46100
  }
]
```

What I need to do is take the field value from the object and use it to find the key that it matches in the second object and retrieve the value of it, so in this case I should be getting 14.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't really understand how the two objects relate... But you could try do it with the `Array.prototype.find` method maybe?

Comment: Get the values of all object or just the first one ?

Comment: `var values = secondArr.map(e => e[firstObj.defs.field])` and you will get all the values.

Comment: @Redu Thanks for that!

Comment: is this query resolved or you still need a solution ?

Comment: It is resolved thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ES6, you can try this:

```
const field = lookupObject.defs.field;

const matches = array.map(arrayItem => {
    return {
        field,
        value: arrayItem[field]
    }
});
```

The `matches` array will contain the data you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help